# How to download Twitter video that stored on the Twitter CDN from a webapp

Tags: video, twitter

I am developing a project that user can download video of a tweet.

I can find the original video link given a tweet link.

For example:

This tweet (https://twitter.com/youhaveagift/status/1735368654609629240) contains video from twitter CDN (https://video.twimg.com/ext_tw_video/1735368028454567940/pu/vid/avc1/720x1280/K1xz9gR_dzGv3ad2.mp4?tag=12)

If we right click on the video, there is option to download this video.

I would like to ask how to show a download button on the webpage to download this video?

Any suggestion will help, thanks in advance.